# Pass values in a Python list values without parentheses to variable

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a `python` script which is programmatically loading data from a flat file into a `postgresql`/`Redshift` database using the `psycopg2`.

The script is trying to pass a variable of column names to the copy command, like so:

```
COPY FROM 's3://....' TO table_name (column_names);
```

The column names are in a list:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

When I pass that list as variable to the database query, the command is evaluated as:

```
COPY FROM 's3://....' TO table_name ['A', 'B', 'C'];
```

The database command expects the

```
COPY FROM 's3://....' TO table_name (A, B, C);
```

I guess I need to take a list, strip the parentheses and pass as a string?  I could do that as a `for loop` and format the string correctly.

Is there a way to format a list to return as (A, B, C)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily with string manipulation.

```
"(" + ", ".join(column_names) + ")"
```